# R+ comparing loop index variable against ith value in array

Tags: r, loops

is it possible to compare the index variable (i) used in a for loop against the value of ith cell in an array?

basically is the below possible in R?

```
rowi<-c(1,2,3,6,7,9,13,16,17,21,23,25,27,29,30,32,33)
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  if(i==rowi[i])
   ....
}
```

it screams I have called a list where it should be atomic value

Comment: This code runs for me. Can you show the `...` part??

Comment: @ Jlhoward the ... is simply df[i]<-as.factor(df[i])

Comment: OK. If `df` is a data.frame, then, e.g., `df[i]` returns a list. Try `df[[i]] <- as.factor(df[[i]])`, or, alternatively, `df[,i] <- as.factor(df[,i])`.

Comment: Is the idea to convert the columns identified in `rowi` to factors?? If so, just use `df[,rowi] <- as.factor(df[,rowi])`. The confusing bit for me is why would you call a set of column numbers `rowi`??

Comment: thanks @Jlhoward, realized that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform a loop:

```
rowi<-c(1,2,3,6,7,9,13,16,17,21,23,25,27,29,30,32,33)
> rowi[rowi==seq_along(rowi)]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

The function `seq_along(rowi)` generates a sequence of integers, starting from 1 and ending at the last index of the vector `rowi`. The elements of the two vectors are compared with `==`, yielding `TRUE` for each element for which `rowi[i]` is equal to `i`, and those elements are thereby selected from the original vector with a method known as "logical subsetting".

Alternatively you can obtain the values of the indices `i` with `rowi[i]` equal to `i` by using the function `which()`:

```
> which(rowi==seq_along(rowi))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Knowing these indices will allow you to run a loop that is much shorter than the one in your example (provided that you actually need a loop for what you intend to do in `...`), since those are the only values of `i` that need to be considered, as they are the only ones fulfilling the condition.

Comment: using which doesnt allow me to perform a if operation in this case; Im trying to convert specific columns to factors where the column numbers are in an array called rowi and the df is the dataframe in which the data type for the columns need to be converted

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. The function `which()` makes the `if` statement superfluous, as it returns only the values of `i` for which the `if` statement in your example is evaluated as `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. And the code you posted doesn't work. These changes do work, and you get output:

```
rowi<-c(1,2,3,6,7,9,13,16,17,21,23,25,27,29,30,32,33)
for(i in 1:length(rowi)){
    if(i==rowi[i])
        print(rowi[i])
}
```

yielding

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```